# I deleted some old versions of gems and now rails is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So long story short I was running out of room on my dual booted ubuntu laptop. I decided to delete some older versions of gems to make some room which worked. Great, except now I can't get rails to work on my machine anymore - rails console and rails server is failing. This is the error I see when I type in rails s;

```
jmtoporek@jmtoporek-laptop:~/rails/pskr2$ rails s
/home/jmtoporek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/hpricot-0.8.6/lib/fast_xs.so: [BUG]  Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

/usr/bin/rails: line 104:  4807 Aborted                 /usr/bin/ruby     /usr/share/rails/railties/bin/rails ${OVERWRITE_OPTION} "${RAILS_PKG_DESTINATION}" "${INTERNAL_OPTIONS}" -d $DATABASE
ln: target `/home/jmtoporek/rails/pskr2/s/vendor/' is not a directory: No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/jmtoporek/rails/pskr2/s/vendor/rails': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/jmtoporek/rails/pskr2/s/doc/api': No such file or directory
```

Comment: so what you want from us? you know what you did. you know, you can solve it by undoing your actions (reinstall the gems)

Comment: I did reinstall some of the gems, but it did not do the trick. Thats why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled railties - despite the fact that the gem was already installed something must have gotten messed up. I reinstalled railties, which fixed the issue. I wish I had looked closer at the error message. It appears that there is a copy of railties inside the rails gem directory.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose reinstalling rails should be enough, because it installs several gems to run properly. Simply run `gem install rails` and see if it works again.

Also, if you use RVM, you can use a different installation executing something like this:

`rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails328 --create --default`

..and then, installing rails again:

`gem install rails`

Just remember this last solution requires you to install all other gems as well.

Comment: You know oddly enough I did reinstall rails and it did not resolve the issue. I do use rvm, so perhaps if I had done it the way you proposed it would have done the trick. It's fixed for now. Only after I reinstalled railties was the problem resolved. And thing was I never uninstalled rails 3.2.8, nor railties 3.2.8, just all the sub 3.2 versions. I love rails until I do something like this and make a mess. What was amazing is I hit the memory limit on a 12GB partition (99%) and after I removed older versions of gems I got it down to 65%. Gems take up a lot of memory.

Comment: I don't know if this will work but I am upvoting it. Thanks for taking the time to comment without making some condescending comment, I really appreciate that.